# Everything turns into a word doc

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

All my desktop shortcuts look like the Word icon. When I use a shortcut to try to open a program, Word 2010 opens and then it tries to open the program so a file conversion window appears! What's going on? How do I get the shortcuts back?

Comment: We need more information...When did this happen? How did it happen? Have you tried booting in Safe Mode? Does it still occur then? I'd suggest running virus and malware scans, and possibly System Restore to a date prior to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do a restart. Press F8 to Open Boot options. Choose Repair Mode and if required the System will Restore itself to a previous point(if available).

Similar Problem [solved] : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/ms-word-has-hijacked-my-desktop-and-all-icons-have/a5d901b5-a08d-4e1f-9f7f-efbedacdc799

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was hitting F8 until I could get into Safe Mode.  I then picked an earlier date in the computer's life and did a restart.  Everything went back to normal and I didnt lose any files.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SuperUser...

Windows uses something called file association to know what software to load with which file (so word documents are exameple.doc or example.docx most commonly). You sound like your file association for .lnk (shortcut files) has been changes to try and use word.

What you need to do is go to Start Menu > Run > type regedit > press ok

Expand HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Scroll down to .lnk expand the + and check what is listed under ShellNew it should have things like Handler, IconPath, etc.

These will have a column called Data which you will need to add to your question in order for me to help you change them back to what they should be..

Any questions please comment underneath and I'll get back to you...

Comment: This would just have turned into a word doc

Comment: What would have what?